# Найти число с максимальной суммой делителей

Tags: pascal

Дано число N. Найти из диапазона от 1 до N число с максимальной суммой делителей (включая непростые делители, 1 и само число). Если таких чисел несколько, выведите любые из них.
Pascal ABC.

Comment: @nadegda-sp, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: А в чём проблема? Прямое решение (перебирать в цикле числа, считать для каждого делители и их сумму, запоминать в переменной текущее наибольшее) не подходит?

Comment: как правильно в паскале написать то что мы считаем для каждого делителя и их суммы?

Comment: Ну, это уж совсем основы, тут мы вряд ли поможем, посмотрите в любой учебник или спросите у одноклассников.

Comment: не помню, как в паскале, а на питоне в три строки
    
    N = 19 # заданное число
    z = max([(sum([x for x in xrange(1, t+1) if t % x == 0]), t) for t in xrange(1,N+1)])
    print ("max  = %d, n = %d"%z)

переводите:)

Comment: @KoVadim: На C# тоже несложно:

    Enumerable.Range(1, N)
              .Select(n =>
                      {
                          n,
                          s = Enumerable.Range(1, n - 1).Where(i => n % i == 0).Sum()
                      })
              .Aggregate((max, next) => next.s > max.s ? next : max)
              .n;

В вашем коде, если я не ошибаюсь, находится максимум, а не значение, на котором он достигается.

Comment: в моем примере z - это тупл (такой себе список, в данном случае из двух чисел). max, если ему дать массив туплов, находит максимальное по первому элементу тупла. А он является суммой делителей. Второй элемент - это само число.

> В вашем коде, если я не ошибаюсь, находится максимум, а не значение, на котором он достигается. 

Поэтому в моем коде находиться и значение максимума, и число, на котором он достигается.  Смотрите последний print.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это просьба сделать учебное задание за пользователя

Answer (score 1):

Если сначала прикинуть, где вообще находятся делители любого числа, то вы обнаружите, что искать делители числа N следует лишь в диапазоне от 0 до N/2, плюс еще делитель N. Поясню на примере числа 36:

```
 Делители: 1,2,3,4,6,9,12,18 ... и 36. Как видите, все неизвестные делители находятся лишь в первой половине числа, т.е от 1 до N/2 плюс само N, т.е 36.
```

Это очевидно.

**Следующий момент:**

```
Раз мы ищем сумму всех делителей числа, то по логике вещей, те числа, что ближе к N будут иметь сумму делителей больше, чем те, что дальше. Но! Это не всегда так, поэтому в используемом ниже алгоритме диапазон поделен лишь поровну, чего в общем-то достаточно.
```

Я предложу такой алгоритм:

```
    int N = 20000;
    int dp_summ = 0, dp=0, ch = 0;

    for(int i=N/2;i<=N;i++)
    {
        int ost = (i%10);
        if(dp>2 && (ost==1 || ost==3 || ost==7 || ost == 9)) continue;

        int curr = 0, curr_dp=0;
        for(int j=1;j<=i/2;j++) if(i%j==0) {curr+=j; curr_dp++;}
        curr+=i;curr_dp++;
        if(curr>dp_summ) {dp_summ=curr; dp=curr_dp; ch = i;}
    }

    printf("Digit is %i   have sum of dividers = %i, diveders = %i\n",ch,dp_summ,dp);
```

Также в алгоритм можно внедрить какой-либо другой алгоритм для ускорения. Например, [алгоритм Люка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B_%D0%9B%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B0) для проверки числа на простоту. Но это уже пускай останется вам в качестве самостоятельной работы =)

Задача ваша среднего уровня, интересная даже малость) Вот мне самому интересно найти наиболее корректное решение. Вся обоснованная критика в адрес приведенного выше алгоритма только приветствуется.

Answer (score 0):

Недавно помогал знакомой оптимизировать алгоритм просчета суммы делителей, так что только немножко изменил заготовку. Код делфийский, но я думаю, вам не составит труда переделать под паскаль.

```
function TForm1.FindMaxDel(x: integer): integer; // х - диапазон
var
n, n2, s, i, maxDel:integer;
del: integer;
begin
MaxDel:= 0;  //максимальная сумма делителей

for n := 1 to x do  // пробегаем весь диапазон
  begin
    s:= 0;   // тут обнуляем сумму делителей
    // Тут начинается магия                  
    if n mod 2 = 0 then
      del:= 2
    else
      if n mod 3 = 0 then
        del:= 3
      else
        if n mod 5 = 0 then
          del:= 5
        else
          if n mod 7 = 0 then
            del:= 7
          else
            del:= 0;
    // тут заканчивается магия
    // дальше идет расчет суммы делителей
    if del = 0 then
      inc(s)
    else
      for i:=1 to (n div del) do
        if n mod i =0 then
          S:=i+s;    
    s:= s + n;

    // Если сумма делителей больше текущей, то отмечаем её
    if s > MaxDel then
      begin
        MaxDel:= s;
        Result:= n;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: А почему вы пробегаетесь до x? Можно сократить время пробега, если посли нахождения простого делителя сразу делить `x` на него. Так вы найдёте множество простых делителей, а имея его на руках, сумму посчитать несложно.

Comment: > Найти из диапазона от 1 до N  

этот диапазон надо весь пройти, в "for n := 1 to x do" х - это и есть установленный пользователем диапазон, внутри которого будет осуществляться поиск числа.  Если бы вы посмотрели код дальше, то увидели бы магию, которая сокращает диапазон поиска сумм делителей для конкретного числа:  

  if n mod 2 = 0 then
      del:= 2
  ...
  for i:=1 to (n div del) do
  ...

Comment: @teanЫЧ: ну, это работает только для маленьких делителей. А для числа `11*13*17*19*23*29*31*37` ваш алгоритм будет считать достаточно долго.